# Angular 5 Best practice to store settings for individual developers

Tags: angular, github, angular5

Right now some settings are stored in "src/assets/config, "config.dev.json" and "config.prod.json". These are the common settings that get pushed to the repository, but some settings, like user id must be stored locally.

I know that I can just add files and folders to .gitignore, but is there a best practice how to do this?

I'm grateful for links to architectural role models too!

Comment: Why not to use Enviroment files for the same?

Comment: Pardeep, those get pushed to github and shared, I need to keep developer specific settings separate.

Comment: Even you can add enviroment folder into `.gitignore`